# How to animate object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation

I want to animate an object (in my example, a div), to move 100px from left to right, using JUST javascript (no JQuery allowed).

Here is my code http://pastebin.com/HvNjQES0.

```
function move(elem) {
    var st = 0;
    console.log("ELEM " + elem);

    function animate() {
        st++;
        console.log(st);
        elem.style.left = st + 'px';
        console.log("elem" + elem.style.left);
        if (st == 100) // check finish condition
            clearInterval(id)
    }
    id = setInterval(animate, 10);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="move(text_ex)">Click</button>       
<div id="text_ex" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>
```

What is the problem with my code (it won't work)?

Any other solution is welcomed.

Comment: It's way more helpful to set up your code on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It's also considered very important to describe exactly what goes wrong with your code: what exactly you expect it to do, and what it does instead, in other words. Also include any error messages or other explicit feedback provided by the web browser.

Comment: Do you see any of the statements in the console? Elements which are not positioned `absolute` or `relative` ignore the `left` property. See http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/left. This might be the problem.

Comment: just a tip: unlike alert, you can pass multiple arguments to console.log and they don't even have to be strings: `console.log("elem", elem.style.left)`

Comment: @bloomingsmilez: In addition to that you have to make `id` **local**. Otherwise, clicking on the button twice, before the first animation finished, will result in an infinite animation. Or make sure you always call `clearInterval` at the beginning of the function. http://jsbin.com/epubez/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:absolute` to your div and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to enable the `div` movable, you need either set its `display` style as `absolute` or `relative`.

Second, in you animate function, you need get the element by `document.getElementById(elem)`";